# Iterate and extract info over div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://boulder.noshdelivery.co/restaurants"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

restaurant_wrapper = soup.find(class_ = "dd_rest_list")

restaurants = restaurant_wrapper.find_all(class_="menu__vendor-name")
restaurant_street_address = restaurant_wrapper.find("span", itemprop="streetAddress")
restaurant_address_locality = restaurant_wrapper.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality")

def extract_restaurant_data(restaurant):
    restaurant_title = restaurant_wrapper.find(class_="menu__vendor-name") 
    return  {
        "title" : restaurant_title.text.strip(),
        "streetAddress": restaurant_street_address.text.strip(),
        "addressLocality": restaurant_address_locality.text.strip()

    }

results = [extract_restaurant_data(restaurant) for restaurant in restaurants]
print(results)
```

I would like to know why this code, prints exactly the same info and does not iterate over the list of restaurants.

My output is this

```
{'title': '5280 Cafe At Rallysport', 'streetAddress': '2727 29th St.', 
'addressLocality': 'Boulder'},  
{'title': '5280 Cafe At Rallysport', 'streetAddress': '2727 29th St.', '   addressLocality': 'Boulder'}........
```

The info is the same. I do not know why my code does not iterate over the different names from the list of "restaurants"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only did one `find` the data. Do a `find_all` on each section and then `zip` them together!

```
restaurant_details = zip(
    restaurant_wrapper.find_all(class_="menu__vendor-name"),
    restaurant_wrapper.find_all("span", itemprop="streetAddress"),
    restaurant_wrapper.find_all("span", itemprop="addressLocality"),
)
results = [
    {
        "title": title.text.strip(),
        "streetAddress": street_address.text.strip(),
        "addressLocality": address_locality.text.strip()
    }
    for title, street_address, address_locality in restaurant_details
]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

You function has `restaurant_wrapper.find(class_="menu__vendor-name")` written in it, so each time it runs it would print only the first occurence of the class `menu__vendor-name`.

To print a new restaurant's detail in each iteration you would have to access each web element individually.

The code below would allow you to get the details for all restaurants.

```
restwords = restaurant_wrapper.find_all("div", {"class": "dd_restwords"})

def extract_restaurant_data(restaurant):
  title = restaurant.find("div", {"class": "menu__vendor-name"}).text
  streetAddress = restaurant.find("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"}).text
  addressLocality = restaurant.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"}).text

  rest_data = {
      "title": title, 
      "streetAddress": streetAddress, 
      "addressLocality": addressLocality
      }
  
  return rest_data

for restaurant in restwords:
  print(extract_restaurant_data(restaurant))
```